# Slashes for hyphens in compound modifiers

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, compounds, dashes, slash

Take the phrase "a joint FBI-SFPD task force" for example. According to my boss, a slash can stand in for the hyphen. I tend to disagree. Is this grammatically correct? Stylistically acceptable?

Comment: It is no more grammatically correct than it is grammatically incorrect, for no matter of punctuation is ever one of grammar nor vice versa. Moreover, that should be not a hyphen but an en dash.

Comment: Agreeing with @tchrist here, I'd add that "stylistically acceptable" concerns whether some authority accepts the style, and your boss is evidently in authority.  So whatever he says, goes.

Comment: @tchrist Why an en-dash and not a hyphen? Also, thank you for correcting my misuse of grammar.

Comment: The en dash is preferred for things of, um, equal standing, like a *Bose–Einstein condensate* or a *London–New York flight*.  Ug sorry, that’s not the best way to phrase it. I think we have questions about that here somewhere though.

Comment: Chicago Manual of Style 6.80: The en dash can be used in place of a hyphen in a compound adjective when one of its elements consists of an open compound or when both elements consist of hyphenated compounds (see 7.78) ... An abbreviated compound is treated as a single word, so a hyphen, not an en dash, is used in such phrases as “US-Canadian relations” (Chicago’s sense of the en dash does not extend to between).

Comment: @tchrist Above is what I found in Chicago, although I'm curious to learn more about the equal-standing en dash, if I can call it that.

Comment: Yes, the [“relationships and connections”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Relationships_and_connections) use of the en dash is not universally accepted, nor perhaps always entirely clear. I’m most careful of it for ranges myself. I try to  use it if there is a published, established preference as with *Bose–Einstein condensate*, but sometimes it is less than clear. See the Wikipedia link I just gave.

Comment: Thanks, @tchrist! Very interesting. However, my original question stands: Is  the substitution of a slash for a hyphen (or an en dash) acceptable in my original example?

Comment: Slashes cause problems with word wrapping. Also, when over-used, can be incredibly irritating. But this is your boss we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cited (in a comment) a *Chicago Manual of Style* guideline regarding when to use en-dashes, you may be interested in *Chicago*'s views about when using slashes is acceptable. From *Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003), here is the pertinent entry:

> **6.112** *Technical use.* A slash is used in certain contexts to mean *and*.
>
> > [Examples:] an insertion/deletion mutation, a Jekyll/Hyde personality, an MD/PhD student

To the extent that "a joint FBI/SFPD task force" resembles "a Jekyll/Hyde personality," your boss has *Chicago*'s blessing to use a slash in place of a hyphen (or en-dash) between *FBI* and *SFPD*.

On the other hand, if you're looking for support in opposing use of a slash there, you may prefer to cite the views of Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003):

> **Virgule [/].** Known popularly as the "slash," arcanely as the "solidus," and somewhere in between as the "diagonal," the virgule is a mark that doesn't appear much in first-rate writing. Some writers use it to mean "per" {50 words/minute}. Others use it to mean "or" {and/or} or "and" {every employee/independent contractor must complete form XJ42A}. Still others use it to indicate a vague disjunction in which it's not quite an *or* {the novel/novella distinction}. In this last use, the en-dash is usually a better choice. [Cross reference omitted.] In all these uses, there's almost always a better choice than the virgule. Use it as a last resort.

Garner concedes *Chicago*'s point that the slash is used in situations like "joint FBI/SFPD task force," but he leaves no doubt as to his low opinion of that usage. I don't share his aesthetic objection to the slash—particularly in situations where the sense to be conveyed is one of "vague disjunction in which it's not quite an *or*"—but if you do, you have an ally in Garner.

Comment: Chicago Manual of Style is not very good at molecular genetics. "an insertion/deletion mutation" is a single mutation which is either an insertion (an additional unit) or deletion (removal of a unit). It cannot be both. So in that particular context the slash is used for OR not AND. (But actually people often use the neologism, ‘indels.)

Comment: So, to summarise, the hyphen always means "and", while the slash could mean "and" or "or".